# How to repeat select statements in loop pl/sql?

Tags: sql, plsql

I would like to select each row which has 'N' on the column suspend_account from my table to populate my form field below. My form has more fields, however i just put one of them there for example. Any help would be appreciated. this is in pl/sql and i'm using toad for oracle.

-- Select statement --

```
SELECT 
        SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NO,     
        SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NAME, 
        SZRUNSP_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT, 
        SZRUNSP_UNSUSPEND_DATE 

    INTO v_stu_id, 
         v_stu_name, 
         v_sus_account, 
         v_unsus_date 
        FROM SATURN.SZRUNSP
    WHERE SZRUNSP_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT = ('N')
    ORDER BY SZRUNSP_UNSUSPEND_DATE ASC;
```

-- form field--

```
twbkfrmt.p_TableDataWhite (HTF.formtext (
                                    cname        => '',
                                    csize        => 15,
                                    cmaxlength   => 9,
                                    cvalue       => v_stu_id,
                                    cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure, this is what you need. A cursor is required here, since you need a loop to fetch all the Students where the Suspend_Account = 'N'

```
DECLARE 
    cursor c_cur
        IS
        SELECT 
        SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NO,     
        SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NAME, 
        SZRUNSP_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT, 
        SZRUNSP_UNSUSPEND_DATE 
    WHERE SZRUNSP_SUSPEND_ACCOUNT = ('N')
    ORDER BY SZRUNSP_UNSUSPEND_DATE ASC;
BEGIN
FOR rec in c_cur
LOOP
    twbkfrmt.p_TableDataWhite (HTF.formtext (
                                cname        => '',
                                csize        => 15,
                                cmaxlength   => 9,
                                cvalue       => rec.SZRUNSP_STUDENT_NO,
                                cattributes  => 'style="font-size:12px" readonly ' || disabled))
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @Sudipta Mondal.. i was doing something similar but it started to throw me sh** loads of errors